# ¿Cómo evitar que utf8_decode cambie el carácter "–" por "?"?

Tags: php, utf-8

Tengo este código que extrae información de una página web

```
<?php
// $url = 'https://kacos.pro/';
$url =  'https://reactjs.org/';
// Retrieve the page information
$pageContents = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($pageContents);

// Title
$titleNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $titleNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

// Favicon
$linkNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');
$favicon = '';
foreach ($linkNodes as $key => $node) {
    $link = $linkNodes->item($key);
    if (mb_strpos($link->getAttribute('rel'), 'icon') !== false) {
        $favicon = $link->getAttribute('href');
    }
    if (mb_strpos($link->getAttribute('rel'), 'apple-touch-icon') !== false) {
        $favicon = $link->getAttribute('href');
    }
}

if (mb_strpos($favicon, 'https') === false) {
    if (mb_substr($favicon, 0, 1) !== '/') {
        $favicon = '/' . $favicon;
    }
    if (mb_substr($url, -1) === '/') {
        $favicon = mb_substr($url, 0, -1) . $favicon;
    } else {
        $favicon = $url . $favicon;
    }
}

// Get meta tags
$metaNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$description = '';
foreach ($metaNodes as $key => $node) {
    $meta = $metaNodes->item($key);
    if (mb_strpos($meta->getAttribute('property'), 'og:description') !== false) {
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if (mb_strpos($meta->getAttribute('name'), 'description') !== false) {
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}

echo ($favicon) . PHP_EOL;
echo ($title) . PHP_EOL;
echo ($description) . PHP_EOL;
```

E imprime esto:

> ```
> https://reactjs.org/favicon.ico
> React – A JavaScript library for building user interfaces
> A JavaScript library for building user interfaces
> ```

Funciona bien para lo que necesito, hasta que me encuentro con caracteres especiales como *ñ* o vocales con tilde.
Por ejemplo para esta url `https://kacos.pro/`, imprime esto:

> ```
> https://kacos.pro/safari-pinned-tab.svg
> Home is where you can code without pants | Carlos ProaÃ±o - Beta
> Husband, father, developer, friend. Currently a full stack developer. Born in Ecuador and living in MÃ©xico since 2012 (yes, the year the world ended)
> ```

Lo solucioné agregando [`utf8_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) al código, `echo utf8_decode($title) . PHP_EOL;` e imprime

> ```
> https://kacos.pro/safari-pinned-tab.svg
> Home is where you can code without pants | Carlos Proaño - Beta
> Husband, father, developer, friend. Currently a full stack developer. Born in Ecuador and living in México since 2012 (yes, the year the world ended)
> ```

Parece que el problema se solucionó, pero cuando intento extraer la información de `https://reactjs.org/` con [`utf8_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), me cambia el caracter "–" por "?"

> ```
> https://reactjs.org/favicon.ico
> React ? A JavaScript library for building user interfaces
> A JavaScript library for building user interfaces
> ```

Mi versión de PHP es la 7.2.10

#### ¿Existe alguna forma de lograr que no cambie los caracteres pero que decodifique a UTF-8?

**Cabe mencionar que el caracter "–" ([en-dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)), no es el mismo que un "-" ([hyphen](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/hyphen.html))**

---

¿Qué he intentado?

- He intentado hacer lo que mencionan en esta [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328079/4914734), `new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`, pero todavía me imprime "?" en lugar de "–"

Comment: Agrega esto: `@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $pageContents);`, lo encontre en este enlace al parecer funciona [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/8215961)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, `DOMDocument` utiliza `ISO-8859-1` para procesar el contenido, a menos que se indique alguna codificación. Es decir:

```
$pageContents = "<?xml encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" . $pageContents;
```